# hapi.js is not returning a value from mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, hapi.js

I am new to hapi and mysql and I am having trouble returning a value in the browser. It is working in the `console.log` but when going to `localhost:3000/hello` it is getting an error.

```
    server.route({
    method:'GET',
    path:'/hello',
    handler:function(request,h) {

        connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;

            console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);

            return ('The solution is: ', results[0].solution)
          });

    }
});
```

the console.log is working and is returning `The solution is:  2` but when i go to `http://localhost:3000/hello` the error is `Error: handler method did not return a value, a promise, or throw an error`

I search for a solution and tried returning a value like this:

```
server.route({
    method:'GET',
    path:'/hello',
    handler:function(request,h) {

        connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function (error, results, fields) {
            if (error) throw error;

            console.log('The solution is: ', results[0].solution);

            return ('The solution is: ', results[0].solution)
          });
        // I returned 'hello world' outside the connection.query
          return "hello world"
    }
});
```

Now this is working except the input is `hello world` instead of `The solution is:  2`

How can I return `return ('The solution is: ', results[0].solution)` ?

Thank you in advance
if it's helpful, here is my connection variable.

```
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : 'password',
  database : "dbname",
  insecureAuth : true
});
```

Comment: Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321). If your MySQL library doesn't handle promises, you may wrap the call to `query` in a new `Promise` as shown in the accepted answer.

Comment: Okay, I solved it. Thanks